# How to show dialog box with two buttons ( Continue / Close ) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I want to create a warning dialog box which asks the users if the information typed during signup was correct, and asks him wether he want to continue or close that dialog and correct his information.

Comment: Even [`Task Dialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in new Windows versions doesn't have the common buttons with this caption. Talking about task dialog you might use the custom buttons (see the screenshot from the link). In standard [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there's IMHO no way how to change the button captions. So the easiest way is to create your own one, but maybe I'm wrong... Maybe [`this`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/messagebox/article.php/c10873) way ?

Comment: @TLama Task dialog lets you give the buttons any name you fancy

Comment: @David, I was talking about `dwCommonButtons`, those you can't change or am I wrong ?

Comment: @tlama that's not really the point since one of the goals of task dialog is to allow buttons with any caption

Comment: Continue and Close mean pretty much the same thing. You need better names. Read the windows ux guidelines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var
  td: TTaskDialog;
  tb: TTaskDialogBaseButtonItem;
begin
  td := TTaskDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    td.Caption := 'Warning';
    td.Text := 'Continue or Close?';
    td.MainIcon := tdiWarning;
    td.CommonButtons := [];

    tb := td.Buttons.Add;
    tb.Caption := 'Continue';
    tb.ModalResult := 100;

    tb := td.Buttons.Add;
    tb.Caption := 'Close';
    tb.ModalResult := 101;

    td.Execute;

    if td.ModalResult = 100 then
      ShowMessage('Continue')
    else if td.ModalResult = 101 then
      ShowMessage('Close');

  finally
    td.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

**Note:** [This will only work on Windows Vista or later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6344538/243614).

Comment: +1 for complete answer, (although `close` is a very bad caption for a button because of its general ambiguity and meaninglessness :-)

Comment: .. and only when themes are enabled. I remember David has made a note on this somehere.. update - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6344538/243614)

Comment: Close generally means close the dialog and is used when there are no options. Continue and Cancel are most often paired.

Comment: @David - Thanks, it's very nice to see that it has been resolved in just about a few months!

Answer (score 8):

if delphi then

```
if mrYes=MessageDlg('Continue?',mtwarning,[mbYes, mbNo],0) then 
  begin
        //do somthing
  end
else
exit; //go out
```

Comment: what about writing ( Continue and Close ) instead of ( Yes and No ) ?

Comment: you can only have this for the messageDlg mbYes, mbNo, mbOK,mbCancel,mbAbort, mbRetry, mbIgnore, mbAll, mbNoToAll, mbYesToAll, mbHelp

Comment: IMO, it's better (easier, simpler, less code, etc.) to stick with the standard buttons.  I suspect that the reason for the specific continue/close captions is based on specifications/requirements that were written without knowledge of the standard captions.  If this is the case, the requirements should be changed.

Comment: @chris the standard changed ages ago when Vista came out. Read about task dialog.

Comment: Ages ago.. yes.. Still not available to the majority of windows users, particularly enterprise users.  I do like the task dialog, but it's overkill for such a simple confirmation prompt, unless those Continue/Close captions are necessary/justified, which I suspect they aren't.

Comment: That OS task dialogs aren't available doesn't mean that dialogs with more descriptive button captions aren't available, @Chris. And it's only a new standard on Windows; descriptive captions have been common on Macs for a decade or two.

Comment: @chris dialogs with descriptive captions, as opposed to yes, no, cancel are just better

Answer (score 8):

```
var
  AMsgDialog: TForm;
  abutton: TButton;
  bbutton: TButton;
begin

  AMsgDialog := CreateMessageDialog('This is a test message.', mtWarning,[]);
  abutton := TButton.Create(AMsgDialog);
  bbutton :=  TButton.Create(AMsgDialog);

  with AMsgDialog do

    try

      Caption := 'Dialog Title' ;
      Height := 140;
      AMsgDialog.Width := 260 ;

      with abutton do
      begin
        Parent := AMsgDialog;
        Caption := 'Continue';
        Top := 67;
        Left := 60;
        // OnClick :tnotyfievent ;
      end;

      with bbutton do
      begin
        Parent := AMsgDialog;
        Caption := 'Close';
        Top := 67;
        Left := 140;
        //OnClick :tnotyfievent ;
      end;

       ShowModal ;

    finally
      abutton.Free;
      bbutton.Free;
      Free;
    end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229699/ok-to-use-virtualprotect-to-change-resource-in-delphi):

```
procedure HookResourceString(rs: PResStringRec; newStr: PChar);
var
  oldprotect: DWORD;
begin
  VirtualProtect(rs, SizeOf(rs^), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @oldProtect);
  rs^.Identifier := Integer(newStr);
  VirtualProtect(rs, SizeOf(rs^), oldProtect, @oldProtect);
end;

const
  SContinue = 'Continue';
  SClose = 'Close';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HookResourceString(@SMsgDlgOK, SContinue);
  HookResourceString(@SMsgDlgCancel, SClose);
  if MessageDlg('My Message', mtConfirmation, [mbOK, mbCancel], 0) = mrOK then
  begin
    // OK...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1, you can also use the [`hook`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/messagebox/article.php/c10873) to get the handle to the message box and then use [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of the button you want to change and set its text by using [`SetDlgItemText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); quite overkill, I know :) But the worst on this solution is that you have to use the DLL library for that hook.

Comment: @TLama - No need for a dll, the dialog window is in the same thread. Can also hook the dialog without using SetWindowHookEx, in a message handler, such as WM_ENABLE, WM_ACTIVATE, or in ActiveFormChange etc..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, are you sure with that ? I tried to catch the `WM_ACTIVATE` in the main form's `WndProc` at message box showing but I didn't get the notification. Are you sure the `MessageBox`'s window doesn't have its own message loop ?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you're not restoring the original `Identifier` values afterwards, so every dialog displayed after this will show `Continue` instead of `OK` and `Close` instead of `Cancel`. There are other, better alternatives to this solution; they've even been posted here in this thread. (Not downvoting, just pointing out the problem.)

Comment: @TLama - Sorry for the confusion, it's my incorrect wording. I should possibly say 'hack' the dialog, instead of 'hook' the dialog. In a WM_ACTIVATE handler that's calling the dialog, you can loop forms when active is WA_INACTIVE, see if the activating form is a 'TMessageForm' (in case of a TaskDialog get the activating windows class name to compare...), etc..